# Is there any function which adds 1 to the array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, output, javascript-objects

I have a given array like this let arr1 =  ['a','b','c'];

And I want output like this ['a1','b1','c1']

Which function should I use?

Comment: `arr1.forEach((e,i,a)=>a[i]=e+'1')`

Answer (score 1):

For this task, the `map` function is the best candidate. It generates a new array by applying the function given as argument to each element.

```js
let arr1 = ['a','b','c'];
console.log(arr1.map(x=>`${x}1`));
```